# Books / tutorials on how to do object oriented analysis and design of algorithms?

Tags: algorithm, uml, oop

There is readily available a lot on info on how to do analysis and design of standard CRUD applications, or at least, applications more geared to the traditional windows application - having a couple of windows, where you click on buttons and then things happen. In the backyard there is some sort of repository where you persist your info, and that is it.

What I am looking for is something more geared toward algorithms. For example, how to do the (object oriented) analysis and design of a neural network? Of a genetic algorithm framework? Of a physics simulation experiment?

Are there any books/referneces on the matter?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You see, you must grasp the notion of OO design and get a vision by developing small applications, practicing and applying the very same principles in your domain that might be Embedded Systems, OS design, Genetic Algorithm or anything else.

Even though OO is best suited for developing (large) business application, for every domain there might be some domain specific languages (DSL) that fits well and solves common problems idiomatically.

Example are [R](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_%28programming_language%29), Functional Programming languages (ML, F#, Haskell, Clojure ), Math specific tools (Matlab) and ...

All in all, a general practical Software Engineering book may be helpful for you like Ian Sommerville's book which gives you an overall view.